# Adding group of fields in custom module

Tags: 7

I am trying to programmatically create a content type with 2 fieldsets, where the second one have an "Add more" option to create multiple set of fields. I looked for a working example to create multiple sets of fields, save, and edit them. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any. My module is creating, editing and saving the content type without 'add more' option.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Could you post the code you've already tried?

Comment: Sounds like you're building a lot of stuff that already exists. Is there a reason why you want to code this yourself instead of using [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) for the fieldsets and [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) to export it to code?

Comment: @Clive: added the code. Thanks for showing interest.

Comment: @Clive: The brand content type is where 'Add more' is required.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say that there is an only way that I know to have multi-value field groups in Drupal 7 is [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. It is based on [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity). It creates a new entity of which you can add any number of fields, and attaches that to the content type or any other entity you create.

Comment: Not true, that's not the only way. It is possible to create your own multi-value form controls and wrap them into fields. It's just damn hard, but certainly doable. If only I knew exactly how... Examples for Developers contains some hints on the first part.

Comment: @Molot, would you please provide me/us with the information where to find those hints you mentioned?

Comment: field_example.module - "an example field using the Field Types API". `field_example_3text` seems to work as a group of 3 text fields. Not an actual answer, of course, but it is a kind of hint if I understand both the question and the example.